# How to solve the install of RStoolbox in R?

Tags: r

Warning message:
In i.p(...) :
The exit status value is not 0 when installing package 'C:/Users/86151/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpQPvXD7/remotes3b1478bf3f9a/RStoolbox-master'.Installing RStoolbox in R version 4.3.2.

If anyone has any suggestions for successful installation。

Comment: On the website it says "The package is available on CRAN and can be installed as usual via `install.packages("RStoolbox")`. My suggestion is to enter the command `install.packages("RStoolbox")` and select "No" when asked "do you want to install from source?". If you get the same error, please edit your question to include the output of the command `sessionInfo()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I installed successfully using your advice.

Comment: Glad you solved your problem @rang imiss :)